# Transformar duas listas de dados em um gráfico com duas linhas paralelas

Tags: python, matplotlib, gráfico

Galera. Eu estou desde ontem tentando fazer algo que é bem simples no Excel, porem não no Python.

Eu tenho duas listas. Linha1 = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1] e Linha2 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

O que eu preciso fazer é criar um gráfico com essas duas listas e coloca-los em paralelo. Como se fosse um gráfico de progresso. [Exemplo 1](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8RFdG9MC8gi4upKXVVDtLqSSp9H3ix5jlDRAht0mOnzxJFmWq), [Exemplo 2](https://wiki.taticview.com/images/4/48/Gr%C3%A1fico_de_linha_cruzado_2%2Bpt-BR.PNG), [Exemplo 3](http://excelpratico.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2-como-combinar-graficos-no-excel.jpg). Onde por exemplo. Se o valor for 1 a linha sobe, e se o valor for 0 a linha desce.

Eu já consegui criar um gráfico que soma os valores dessas linhas e mostra em um gráfico de barras. Mas isso não me permite ver se o dado em questão está progredindo em relação ao tempo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `matplotlib` para plotar o gráfico, veja só:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def obterProgresso( linha ):
    p = [ 0 ]
    x = 0
    for i in linha:
        if i == 0:
            x-=1
        else:
            x+=1
        p.append(x)

    return p;


Linha1 = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1]
Linha2 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

Prog1 = obterProgresso( Linha1 )
Prog2 = obterProgresso( Linha2 )

print "Linha1 = ", Prog1
print "Linha2 = ", Prog2

plt.plot( Prog1, 'bo' );
plt.plot( Prog1, 'k--', color='blue' );

plt.plot( Prog2, 'ro' );
plt.plot( Prog2, 'k--', color='red' );

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Tempo")
plt.ylabel("Progresso")

plt.show()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Progressões:

```
Linha1 =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
Linha2 =  [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

Comment: Sim. Muito obrigado ^^. Aqui está o que eu estou querendo fazer "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gHjtnm8OKtNH0Evlhv6Src1VIIZ1_BXR " é um programinha pra eu acompanhar meu progresso em fazer minhas tarefas diarias.

Comment: Pronto. Aqui está a versão atual " https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zZYnXYcG6y_cbrtWXu7sKMD7UBMPl9-x ", é o ponto que eu queria. ^^. Vou chamar de Gerenciador tarefas DDN